# VueJS How can I use computed property with v-for

Tags: javascript, vue.js, computed-properties

How can I use computed property in lists. I am using VueJS v2.0.2.

Here's the HTML:

```
<div id="el">
    <p v-for="item in items">
        <span>{{fullName}}</span>
    </p>
</div>
```

Here's the Vue code:

```
var items = [
    { id:1, firstname:'John', lastname: 'Doe' },
    { id:2, firstname:'Martin', lastname: 'Bust' }
];

var vm = new Vue({
    el: '#el',
    data: { items: items },
    computed: {
        fullName: function(item) {
            return item.firstname + ' ' + item.lastname;
        },
    },
});
```

Answer (score 100, accepted):

You can't create a computed property for each iteration. Ideally, each of those `items` would be their *own* component so each one can have its own `fullName` computed property.

What you can do, if you don't want to create a `user` component, is use a method instead. You can move `fullName` right from the `computed` property to `methods`, then you can use it like:

```
{{ fullName(user) }}
```

Also, side note, if you find yourself needing to pass an arguments to a `computed` you likely want a method instead.

Comment: What if you need to use fullName more than once and the fullName method is a complex function that would be really expense to do 10 times for each iteration?  I think @PanJunie's solution would be much better in that situation.

Comment: I'd honestly do this much higher up in state. The computed approach below would break if you're working on sorted version of items. I was definitely going for safety here. It makes a lot more sense to me to make the data as reusable as possible much higher up.

Comment: My problem is, that array can change based on other items that get selected and deselected which triggers the reactivity of the array itself so I can't really do it at a higher level, I don't think, other than possibly creating a filter and adding in additional properties to the objects in the array at that point (which is not a terrible idea but just causes an addition looping through the array to do all that - twice is better than 10 times, I guess).

Answer (score 52):

What you're missing here is that your `items` is an array, which holds all the items, but the `computed` is a single `fullName`, which just can't express all the `fullName`s in `items`. Try this:

```
var vm = new Vue({
    el: '#el',
    data: { items: items },
    computed: {
        // corrections start
        fullNames: function() {
            return this.items.map(function(item) {
                return item.firstname + ' ' + item.lastname;
            });
        }
        // corrections end
    }
});
```

Then in the view:

```
<div id="el">
    <p v-for="(item, index) in items">
        <span>{{fullNames[index]}}</span>
    </p>
</div>
```

The way Bill introduces surely works, but we *can* do it with computed props and I think it's a better design than `method` in iterations, especially when the app gets larger. Also, `computed` has a performance gain compared to `method` on some circumstances: http://vuejs.org/guide/computed.html#Computed-Caching-vs-Methods

Comment: Im using this for highlighting a row in a `:class` directive works better than a method.

Comment: This is less portable. If you wanted to go through a sorted copy of `items` and get the fullName this would fail. What should really be done is a "user" component, which takes a user object, that has a fullName computed property.

Comment: Why will it fail when `items` are sorted? @BillCriswell

Comment: If you were to do `v-for="item in sortedVersionOfItems"` the `index` would be off.

Answer (score 11):

I like the solution posted by PanJunjie潘俊杰. It gets at the heart of the issue by only iterating over `this.items` once (during the component creation phase), and then caching the result. This is of course the key benefit for utilizing a computed prop instead of a method.

```
computed: {
    // corrections start
    fullNames: function() {
        return this.items.map(function(item) {
            return item.firstname + ' ' + item.lastname;
        });
    }
    // corrections end
}
```

.

```
<p v-for="(item, index) in items">
    <span>{{fullNames[index]}}</span>
</p>
```

The only thing I don't like is that, in the DOM markup, `fullNames` is accessed by the list index. We could improve that by using `.reduce()` instead of `.map()` in the computed prop to create an Object with a key for each `item.id` in `this.items`.

> Consider this example:

```
computed: {
    fullNames() {
        return this.items.reduce((acc, item) => {
            acc[item.id] = `${item.firstname} ${item.lastname}`;
            return acc;
        }, {});
    },
},
```

.

```
<p v-for="item in items" :key="`person-${item.id}`">
    <span>{{ fullNames[item.id] }}</span>
</p>
```

Note: the above example assumes that `item.id` is unique, such as from typical database output.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe add another v-for that iterates through a one-item-long list:

```
<div id="el">
    <p v-for="item in items">
        <template v-for="fullName in [item.firstName + ' ' + item.lastName]">
            <span>{{fullName}}</span>
        </template>
    </p>
</div>
```

Not nice, but that's what you're looking for: an object around that span that has a property called fullName that contains that specific value.

And it's not just a vanity feature, because we may need to use that value at more than one place, eg.:

```
<span v-if="...">I am {{fullName}}</span>
<span v-else-if="...">You are {{fullName}}</span>
<span v-else>Who is {{fullName}}?</span>
```

My use case was that I was constructing dates in v-for loops (yes, another calendar), like:

```
<v-row v-for="r in 5">
    <v-col v-for="c in 7">
        <template v-for="day in [new Date(start.getTime() + 24*60*60*1000*((c-1) + 7*(r-1)))]">
            <span>
                Some rendering of a day like {{day.getYear()}} and
                {{day.getMonth()}} etc.
            </span>
        </template>
    </v-col>
</v-row>
```

(For brevity I omitted the `:key="whatever"` settings)

I admit that the nicest way would be to move that  to a separate component, but if we create a new component for every two-liner like this, and use that component only at this single place, then we just pollute another namespace.

Maybe a `v-let="day as new Date(...)"` directive would be handy for such purpose.

Answer (score -2):

you have to pass argument in the function call

```
 <div id="el">
       <p v-for="item in items">
           <span>{{fullName(item)}}</span>
       </p>
 </div>
```

Comment: [A code-only answer is not high quality](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers). While this code may be useful, you can improve it by saying why it works, how it works, when it should be used, and what its limitations are. Please [edit] your answer to include explanation and link to relevant documentation.