# How to optimize data binding on table representing data organized as columns

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I can't get how to properly use computed properties when displaying data organized as columns with table.
The full example of my code is available at [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ncpdwywp/3/), here is the short version and description.
I want to render this data as a table:

```
var vueData = {
  objects: [
    {
      name: "objectName",
      objectData: [
        {prop1: "val1", prop2: "val2"}
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

In this `vueData` each element of `objectData` array should be displayed as a column (that column represents data of one month or day). The props in `objectData`'s elements should be displayed not as is, but as computed values. And that displayed values should reflect changes of `vueData`.

So I came to this vue template:

```
<table>
<tr>
  <th>Object Name</th>
  <th>Data Piece 1</th>
  <th>Data Piece 2</th>
</tr>
<template v-for="obj in objects">
<tr> 
  <th rowspan="2">{{ obj.name }}</th>
  <td v-for="dataPiece in obj.objectData">{{ compute(dataPiece.prop1) }}</td>
</tr>
<tr><td v-for="dataPiece in obj.objectData">{{ compute(dataPiece.prop2) }}</td></tr>
</template>
</table>
```

All works fine except that I have used methods, not vue's computed properties. The problem with methods is that their results do not cache and after a single prop change **ALL** cells' values are recomputed.

I could use a vue component for each cell with computed property instead of `td`s , but it looks like overkill, as table can be big.

Is there any another solution from the vue's point of view? (I mean without changing the data structire or appearance of the table, etc).

Comment: This is one of very few shortcomings in Vue: no way to create dynamic computeds. Best idea I have is to implement caching in your `compute` function.

Comment: try the second answer from this post, it should help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40322404/vuejs-how-can-i-use-computed-property-with-v-for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had wanted to do this with a directive, but had no good way of passing the function and the argument, until I remembered I can use `vnode.context` to get context, where I can lookup the function by name rather than passing it as an actual function.

So here's a directive that updates its element's `textContent` with the result of a function call.

```js
var vueData = {
  objects: [{
      name: 'Object 1',
      objectData: [{
          prop1: '1-1-1',
          prop2: '1-1-2'
        },
        {
          prop1: '1-2-1',
          prop2: '1-2-2'
        },
        {
          prop1: '1-3-1',
          prop2: '1-3-2'
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      name: 'Object 2',
      objectData: [{
          prop1: '2-1-1',
          prop2: '2-1-2'
        },
        {
          prop1: '2-2-1',
          prop2: '2-2-2'
        },
        {
          prop1: '2-3-1',
          prop2: '2-3-2'
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      name: 'Object 3',
      objectData: [{
          prop1: '3-1-1',
          prop2: '3-1-2'
        },
        {
          prop1: '3-2-1',
          prop2: '3-2-2'
        },
        {
          prop1: '3-3-1',
          prop2: '3-3-2'
        }
      ]
    },
  ]
};

var vue = new Vue({
  el: document.getElementById("vue"),
  data: vueData,
  methods: {
    compute: function(prop) {
      console.log('computing ' + prop);
      return 'computed(' + prop + ')';
    }
  },
  directives: {
    cache(el, binding, vnode) {
      if (binding.value !== binding.oldValue) {
        el.textContent = vnode.context[binding.arg](binding.value);
      }
    }
  },
  computed: {
    firstProp: function() {
      return this.objects[0].objectData[0].prop1;
    }
  }
});

setTimeout(function() {
  vueData.objects[0].objectData[0].prop1 = 'changed on timeout';
}, 3000);
```

```css
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/vue@latest/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="vue">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Object Name</th>
      <th>Data Piece 1</th>
      <th>Data Piece 2</th>
      <th>Data Piece 3</th>
    </tr>
    <template v-for="obj in objects">
      <tr>
        <th rowspan="2">{{ obj.name }}</th>
        <td v-for="dataPiece in obj.objectData"
          v-cache:compute="dataPiece.prop1"
          >
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td v-for="dataPiece in obj.objectData"
          v-cache:compute="dataPiece.prop2">
        </td>
      </tr>
    </template>
  </table>
  <span>Computed prop1 value = {{ firstProp }}</span>
</div>
```

Comment: @RichardMatsen This one is a little lighter-weight.

Answer (score 1):

I came across this post by LinusBorg [Generating computed properties on the fly](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/generating-computed-properties-on-the-fly/14833/4) where he shows a function for mapping properties to computed's.

I adapted the function for your `objects` variable, as the original was more focused on flat form data (and also a little intimidating).

```js
function mapObjectToComputed({objects}) {
  console.log(objects)
  let res = {};
  objects.forEach((obj,i) => {
    obj.objectData.forEach((dat,j) => {
      ['prop1', 'prop2'].forEach(prop => {
        const propModel = `objects_${i}_${j}_${prop}`;
        const computedProp = {
          get() {
            console.log(`Getting ${propModel}`)
            const val = this.objects[i].objectData[j][prop];
            return val;
          }
        }
        res[propModel] = computedProp;
      })
    })
  })
  return res;
}
```

Here is the inner part of the template. I've changed `prop1` to the new syntax and left `prop2` as you had it.

```js
<template v-for="(obj, i) in objects">
  <tr> 
    <th rowspan="2">{{ obj.name }}</th>
    <td v-for="(dataPiece, j) in obj.objectData">
      {{ fetch(i,j,'prop1') }}
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr><td v-for="dataPiece in obj.objectData">
    {{ compute(dataPiece.prop2) }}
  </td></tr>
</template>
```

The component is

```js
var vue = new Vue({
    el: document.getElementById("vue"),
  data: vueData,
  methods: {
    fetch: function(i,j,prop) {
      const propModel = `objects_${i}_${j}_${prop}`
      return this[propModel];
    },
    compute: function(prop) {
        console.log('computing ' + prop);
        return 'computed(' + prop + ')';
    }
  },
  computed: {
    firstProp: function() {
        return this.objects[0].objectData[0].prop1;
    },
    ...mapObjectToComputed(vueData)
  }
});
```

The console after timeout is

```
Getting objects_0_0_prop1  
computing 1-1-2  
computing 1-2-2  
computing 1-3-2  
computing 2-1-2  
computing 2-2-2  
computing 2-3-2  
computing 3-1-2  
computing 3-2-2  
computing 3-3-2
```

so only `prop2` has recalculated across the board.

Here is the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/47wkovgj/)

Comment: The `set` isn't used and would get an error if it were.

Comment: Cheers, also the get needs to use the enumerated prop.

Comment: It can't call the compute function, so the results aren't right. They don't say "computed".

Comment: Actually, the idea was to replace the compute function - but that function could obviously be passed in.

Comment: Mmm, not so obvious. I guess that's why LinusBorg used events.

Comment: I moved the function definition outside the Vue so the map function could use it. https://jsfiddle.net/47wkovgj/1/

Answer (score 1):

As you mention, you can use a component. That is the cleanest solution I've found. The component is quite simple, tuned to this example. It might be worth using if a computation is particularly expensive.

```js
var vueData = {
  objects: [{
      name: 'Object 1',
      objectData: [{
          prop1: '1-1-1',
          prop2: '1-1-2'
        },
        {
          prop1: '1-2-1',
          prop2: '1-2-2'
        },
        {
          prop1: '1-3-1',
          prop2: '1-3-2'
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      name: 'Object 2',
      objectData: [{
          prop1: '2-1-1',
          prop2: '2-1-2'
        },
        {
          prop1: '2-2-1',
          prop2: '2-2-2'
        },
        {
          prop1: '2-3-1',
          prop2: '2-3-2'
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      name: 'Object 3',
      objectData: [{
          prop1: '3-1-1',
          prop2: '3-1-2'
        },
        {
          prop1: '3-2-1',
          prop2: '3-2-2'
        },
        {
          prop1: '3-3-1',
          prop2: '3-3-2'
        }
      ]
    },
  ]
};

var vue = new Vue({
  el: document.getElementById("vue"),
  data: vueData,
  methods: {
    compute: function(prop) {
      console.log('computing ' + prop);
      return 'computed(' + prop + ')';
    }
  },
  components: {
    cacheResult: {
      props: {
        fn: Function,
        arg: String
      },
      template: '<td>{{fn(arg)}}</td>'
    }
  },
  computed: {
    firstProp: function() {
      return this.objects[0].objectData[0].prop1;
    }
  }
});

setTimeout(function() {
  vueData.objects[0].objectData[0].prop1 = 'changed on timeout';
}, 3000);
```

```css
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/vue@latest/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="vue">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Object Name</th>
      <th>Data Piece 1</th>
      <th>Data Piece 2</th>
      <th>Data Piece 3</th>
    </tr>
    <template v-for="obj in objects">
      <tr>
        <th rowspan="2">{{ obj.name }}</th>
        <td v-for="dataPiece in obj.objectData"
          is="cacheResult"
          :fn="compute"
          :arg="dataPiece.prop1"
          >
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td v-for="dataPiece in obj.objectData"
          is="cacheResult"
          :fn="compute"
          :arg="dataPiece.prop2">
        </td>
      </tr>
    </template>
  </table>
  <span>Computed prop1 value = {{ firstProp }}</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice and compact, everything inside the component.

Comment: How do you explain the `caching` effect?

Comment: If the props don't change, the component isn't updated.

Comment: Perhaps a little too concise - what we see is a `<td>` not dissimilar from the original. Why the difference in behavior?

Comment: Because it is a component, it is something like a `computed` with respect to its props: if no props change, Vue knows that it doesn't need to do anything to the component. It only updates things that depend on the data that changed. Method calls aren't part of dependency tracking and so have to be evaluated on every update.