# referring to a v-for element from inside a getter of computed function

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, v-for

In Vue, I have a v-for loop that renders an input according to an object I have.
The input is with a v-model to a computed function:

```
<template v-for="product in products>"
  {{ product.Name }}: <input type="text" v-model="productAmount">
</template>
```

and accordingly, the computed function with get and setter:

```
computed: {
  productAmount: {
    get () {
      this.product.DefaultAmount
    },
    set (newAmount) {
      // doing something
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is that `this.product` in `get()` is undefined.

Is there a way to refer to a dynamic variable of v-for inside the getter of the computed function?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VueJS How can I use computed property with v-for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40322404/vuejs-how-can-i-use-computed-property-with-v-for)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a `computed` property you should create a child component and pass the product as a property (`<Procuct v-for="p in products" :product="p"/>`).

Alternatively if it is not an expensive operation you could easily replace the `computed` with a `method` instead though and use that:

```
...
methods: {
  getAmountForProduct(product) {
    return product.DefaultAmount
  }
}
```