# How to Vue.js auto click?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

After searching the products on the search button, I have to list them in the background and make a selection.

Codes:

```
//The area I want clicked each time
<div v-for="(item, index) in filteredProducts" @click="addToList(item)"></div>
```

How can I get it to take action automatically?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean "take action?"  Do you want to run `addToList(item)` function every time someone searches a product?

You can use a watcher or computed property and run that addToList function when filteredProducts change, instead of a click event. I don't see why you would want to "auto click" on a div.

If you could further explain your question and provide a larger codebase, I could help better.

Answer (score 0):

You Can Use computed
See This [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40322404/vuejs-how-can-i-use-computed-property-with-v-for)

```
computed: {
    addToListComputed (item) {
        addToList(item)
    },
},
```